# How massive can a star be at birth?

Tags: mass, star-formation, hypergiants

We have discovered some incredibly massive stars. [R136a1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R136a1), the most massive known star is estimated to have 265 times mass as our Sun. Yet it has been burning for at least a million years, and must have shed a considerable mass as stellar wind. In its infancy, R136a1 must have been much more massive.

Which got me thinking about the question: What is the theoretical limit of mass that a newborn star can have?

Comment: @Aaron: The question you linked seems to be rather vague. What do you mean by "size" when it comes to a star? Mass? Radius? :)

Comment: @Krumia The accepted answer for that question interprets the question as mass.

Comment: @HDE226868: And according to _that_ answer, maximum limit is 2 $M_{Sun}$? :D (Not saying this is not a dupe, but that question should have another answer).

Comment: "The article Stars Have a Size Limit by Michael Schirber, it's about 150 Solar Masses. However, there's the Pistol Star, which is speculated to be 200 SM."

Answer (score 1):

I found a [text](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/ESSAYS/Carr/carr.html) that suggests a Population III star can have a mass between 200 and 10^5$M_{Sun}$. There you can read:

> "...This would apply for VMOs larger than $M_c$ $\approx$ 200 $M_{Sun}$. Stars larger than 150$M_{Sun}$ are termed supermassive objects (SMOs)...".

It seems supermassive stars like R136a1 (with masses in excess 150$M_{Sun}$, the accepted upper limit for a non-pop III star) can be formed by [the collision of massive stars](http://www.astro.uni-bonn.de/de/start/neues/detail/n/2012/august/article/astronomers-crack-mystery-of-the-monster-stars-ras-pr-1254/).

So, It is not difficult to imagine, say, two 150$M_{Sun}$ monsters colliding and forming a 300$M_{Sun}$ object.

Comment: So "Stars larger than $10^5M_{Sun}$ are termed supermassive objects (SMOs), and would collapse directly to black holes due to relativistic instabilities even before nuclear burning, at least if they were metal-free.". You should add that to the answer, I suppose :)

Comment: One more thing to add from the text `It must be stressed that the existence of VMOs and SMOs is entirely speculative and they are invoked primarily for the purpose of making dark matter.` So it seems that 300 times the mass of the sun is the present limit.